# How to linearize a kinematic bicycle model?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory, jacobian

I have the following system:

$$\begin{aligned} x(k+1) &= x(k) + T_sv\cos(\phi(k) + \beta(k)) \\ y(k+1) &= y(k) + T_sv\sin(\phi(k) + \beta(k)) \\ \phi(k+1) &= \phi(k) + \frac{T_sv}{l}\sin(\beta(k))\end{aligned}$$

I am confused how should I put this in linear state-space representation?

1. Clearly there is no equilibria when $v\neq0$, does this mean that I cannot linearize the system or I can linearize it arbitrarily?
2. I got the following ss form using the standard linearization method. Again, how to pick $x_e/u_e$? does it make sense and is there a better way to linearize this system?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\delta x(k+1) \\ \delta y(k+1) \\ \delta \phi(k+1) \\\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-T_sv\sin(\phi_e + \beta_e) \\ 0&1&T_sv\cos(\phi_e + \beta_e) \\ 0&0&1 \\\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\delta x(k) \\ \delta y(k) \\ \delta \phi(k) \\\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}-T_sv\sin(\phi_e + \beta_e) \\ T_sv\cos(\phi_e + \beta_e) \\ \frac{T_sv}{l}\cos(\beta_e) \\\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \delta \beta(k) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
where $ \delta x(k) = x(k) - x_e(k) $

Comment: what do you know about linearization? What have you tried?

Comment: how can variables that depend on the state be in the system matrix? Perhaps things might be clearer if you fixed an operating point. What is are reasonable values for the operating point for the state and the operating point of the control?

Comment: I edited my question, hoping it is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should always start any state space modelling effort by clearly defining (a) the state variables, (b) the inputs, and (c) the outputs. It looks like your state variables are $x,y,\phi$. What physical quantities do those represent? It looks like $\beta$ is an input. What physical quantity does that represent? What outputs are there?
2. You can still linearize the system. You just need to linearize about a nonstationary solution. Assume that $v \neq 0$ and $\beta = 0$ (note that it is common to linearize about the "free-response", e.g. with an input of zero.) Then it looks like $\phi$ is constant and $x$ and $y$ have simple solutions. That looks like a good place to start. Remember that you will need to add in this solution when you want to go from the perturbative analysis back into the first-order approximation of the overall solution.
3. That looks reasonable for the $A$ and $B$ matrices. The reason you have uncertainty at this point is that you skipped the crucial step of defining the solution you are linearizing about before linearizing. $\beta_e(t),x_e(t),x_e(t),\phi_e(t)$ can be any solution you want. I suggested the solution consistent with $\beta_e(t) = 0$, since this would be the most common choice, but you might have some other need. The procedure of linearization cannot tell you this--you as an engineer need to decide what is best for your application.

Comment: I tried to make the question concise so I skipped some details. Nonlinear control theory states that only a small region around the equilibria shares stability with the linearized model, that's why I was confused which equilibrium I should use, but it turns out I can linearize at any point in this case. I simply use linearization as a tool so I never thought it thorough, thanks for your explanation now it makes more senses to me!